# Getting rid of whitespace when using raw EL Expression in NetBeans

Tags: jsf, netbeans, el

I don't know if this is related to NetBeans:

For convenience and readability I often write such code:

```
<p:column headerText="#{msg['name']}">
     #{recruiter.name}
</p:column>
```

Unfortunately, I end up with a whitespace appended to the end of the value of `#{recruiter.name}`:

[image]

However if I write

```
<p:column headerText="#{msg['name']}">
     #{recruiter.name}</p:column>
```

or

```
<p:column headerText="#{msg['name']}">
     <span>#{recruiter.name}</span>
</p:column>
```

or

```
<p:column headerText="#{msg['name']}">
     <h:outputText value="#{recruiter.name}" />
</p:column>
```

Value is displayed as expected:

[image]

I believe NetBeans converts my line break into a white space when not using on of the three syntaxes above but I would like to keep the best readability/simplicity.

Any tips?

Comment: It's HTML specific: http://google.com/search?q=html+white+space+between+inline+elements JSF as being a HTML code generator can do little against it. Your best bet is writing JSF code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML output. Netbeans is just an editor. Like Notepad but then with many more features. It has totally no influence on how JSF behaves runtime.

Comment: If this is HTML specific, I don't get why both `#{recruiter.name}` and `<h:outputText value="#{recruiter.name}" />` syntaxes do not produce the same result?

Comment: Because they do not produce exactly the same HTML output. Rightclick, *View Source* in browser, look at whitespace, etc.